# start command to simultaneously run next and yjs websocket in production

Tags: npm, next.js, websocket, npm-start, yjs

I implemented tldraw and yjs in nextjs and the command and the dev command I use to run it in development is
"concurrently "next" "HOST=localhost PORT=1234 npx y-websocket" --kill-others"
but in production I tried the same time it does not work

I added the start command as "concurrently "next start" "npx y-websocket" --kill-others ",
but the websocket doesnt connect